# how to set a header.php redirect in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

i just want to ask how to set a redirect url in header.php? it seems I am having a redirect loop.

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.sitename.com/category/videos/");
?>
```

Comment: You can use a plugin.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **wp_redirect** instead of the php header() function. Hook the call to the **wp_loaded** to prevent the "headers already sent"-error.

**Example:** (add to functions.php)

```
add_action ('wp_loaded', 'my_redirect_function');

function my_redirect_function() {
    // define when the redirect should be made
    // example: only redirect for the page with slug "about-me"
    if(!is_page( 'about-me' )){
        return;
    }

    // define your url here
    $url = 'http://google.com';
    wp_redirect($url);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: where i gonna put this code mate? on functions.php?

Comment: Yes, you can add that to functions.php. Make sure that you apply a restriction rule for the redirect (like in the example) - otherwise you will end up with a loop, as you said.

Comment: i am still redirecting to the main page. www.sitename.com

Answer (score 0):

You Can put you code directly in header.php
or

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=="your URL When you want redirect")
{
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.sitename.com/category/videos/");
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the following HTML redirect code in a WordPress Page or Post:

```
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.yourURL.com/index.htm">
```

This code tells your browser to auto-refresh the current Web page. When it does, it loads the URL in the "url" string. The "0" attribute associated to "content" determines how many seconds before the redirect takes place. The attributes associated with "content" and "url" are the only ones you should alter.